# Subtracting a passed Linked List in the Method from the Calling Linked List

Tags: java, methods, linked-list

Essentially what this problem does is take in a Linked List as a parameter and subtracts its contents from the calling Linked List if the same contents exist in both. I have to do it this way (so no changing the parameters).

For instance: l1.subtractList(l2) would subtract the contents of l2 from l1.

The trouble here is that the calling Linked List has 2 of the same number and that number is also in the Linked List passed as a parameter. I only have to remove one instance of it as well.

I've managed to subtract everything but that duplicate number, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Keep in mind this is a very new subject to me, so I may be way off base. But I appreciate any and all help you may offer. Thanks.

```
 public void subtractList(LinkedList list)
 {
     Node current = head;
     Node<Integer> temp = list.getFirst();
     Integer count = -1;

    while (current != null)
        if (current == temp){
            count++;
            list.listRemove(count);
            temp = list.getFirst();
         }
        else
       {  
        current = current.getNext();    
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is listRemove method? Why do you need count? Just traverse the argument `list` and check if its element `temp` exists in the calling Linked List. You will need an outer loop traversing the list passed as argument and an inner loop  iterating over the calling list to check the value of the element needing to be removed and to remove it if required

```
while(temp!=null)
{
while(current!=null){
  //Check if element exists in list
  //If yes, remove it from the calling list
}
//Repeat
temp = temp.getNext();
}
```

Comment: It's a specific method to this assignment. I figured it out but your answer helped me get there! Thanks